Can I delete the gch files?
I'm currently working on an embedded system, where I've installed and compiled the OpenCV library. However, I've noticed that the .cpp.gch files are taking up a lot of disk space. Can I delete these .gch files? Will it cause any issues when including OpenCV in my future programs?
As far as I know, .gch files are precompiled header files used to speed up compilation. In the current scenario, the .gch files are likely generated to speed up the compilation of the OpenCV libraries. Therefore, once I have compiled OpenCV and don't need to recompile its source code, I shouldn't need the .gch files anymore. Hence, I believe that deleting them shouldn't cause significant issues. However, I'm not entirely sure.

The build system provides an install command, which will deploy all the parts that are needed for usage of the library to your location of choice. Once you do that, you can nuke the the whole built subtree. Don't try to fish out, or even just use the things directly from the working directory of the build system, you'll just make a mess (and really are reinventing the wheel).
